# printf wont print visible chars

Tags: c

I have this function that reads from a tcp socket, but after I print the incoming message, no characters get printed in the printf() that follows, apart from the newline characters though for some reason.

```
void listenThread(void* context){ //context is a struct containing some userdata
  printf("started listener thread\n");
  struct clientdata *clientdata  = context;
  char* buff[128];
  for (;;){
    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
    read(clientdata->sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    printf("\r%s", buff);
    printf("\n\n[%s]> ", clientdata->username); //the two \n's get printed but the rest after doesn't.
  }
}
```

I'm totally stumped and I'm convinced that the issue is glaringly obvious. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does adding `\n` after `%s` or `[%s]` help?

Comment: `buff` is an array of *pointers* to characters, I think you meant `char buff[128];` instead.

Comment: You should ALWAYS check return value of reading functions (for a TCP socket I would use `recv()`). It returns -1 in error cases, and this is very important because `errno` value helps you to detect for exomple remote socket closures.

Comment: @kuro adding a `\n` after the `[%s]` (`printf("[%s]>\n", clientdata->username);`) seems to do the trick and now the `[%s]` thing prints, however I would like it not to end in a \n. I also tried a nulll byte `\0` but that just brought me back to the same issue.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude BobRun, I tried it and I still have the same problem, seems Kuro might be on the right track though?

Comment: `stdout` is probably line buffered.  You could try using `fflush` after the `printf` or setting `stdout` unbuffered (set `setvbuf`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is *line-buffered*. That means output is actually written to the terminal when

1. The buffer is full
2. The buffer is explicitly flushed with the [`fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) function
3. Or when you print a newline

That's why it seems to work when you print a newline, the buffer is actually written to the terminal.

If you don't want to print the newline, you could explicitly flush the buffer using `fflush(stdout)`.

---

And you should really fix that array issue.

Comment: I didn't know that about stdout, this makes a lot more sense. It works now, thank you. Also, just for your peace of mind I have fixed the array issue ;)